# In a windows batch file, how to recover filename that its name has special characters?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, filenames

I need to invoke a program for each file that exists in a directory, but this files can contain special characters, like accents.

I have this cmd file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b docs\*') do (
    echo "name=%%a"
    program.exe %%a
)
```

If the filename has special characters, the value stored in %%a isn't the same than the filename and program.exe doesn't find the file.

For example, for the file "**Relatório de controle de frequência.pdf**", %%a contains "**Relato´rio de controle de freque^ncia.pdf**" and program.exe gives file not found.

I've tried to put chcp on top of the cmd file with different codepages, but nothing work.

How can I pass to program.exe files with filenames with special characters?

Comment: Quotes. Quotes and more Quotes. You will see it explained as best practice always for batch-files. `program.exe "%%a"`.

Comment: I am pretty sure you will also need to change the code page as well.

Comment: I'd try `program.exe %%~sa` personally - could save a lot of grief

Comment: Nor "%%a" nor %%~sa works